# Why does my Date object in Google Apps Script return NaN

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script

Does Google Apps Script use a funky version of EcmaScript that can't parse a date? How can I parse the date `2011-04-11T19:25:40Z` into a JavaScript Date Object in Google Apps Script?

My log output from below logs `NaN`.

```
function showDate(){
  var d = Date.parse("2011-04-11T19:25:40Z");
  Logger.log(d); // <-- Logs NaN
}
```

**Edit:** http://jsfiddle.net/UTrYm/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The format specified in section [*15.9.1.15*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` so maybe try adding milliseconds to your date format as in `Date.parse("2011-04-11T19:25:40.000Z")`.

Comment: That did it. Is there a reason why JSFiddle is able to parse it but Google Apps Script cannot?

Comment: @citizen conn, I believe Google Apps Script uses Rhino to interpret your JavaScript, whereas JSFiddle is using the interpreter built into your browser.  Rhino is allowed to reject that input according to the spec but your browser's interpreter is being more permissive than the spec requires and not requiring milliseconds.

Comment: My reading of [section 15.9.1.15](https://es5.github.io/x15.9.html#x15.9.1.15) is that milliseconds could be omitted; the absent value should be interpreted as zero.

Comment: @NormalHuman, You're referring to the "one of the following time forms" verbiage?   You're probably right then.  Rhino was being overly strict.

Comment: "was being overly strict" => "is being overly strict." 4 years later, this is still an issue. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Google apps script works fine when you use slashes instead of dashes. Like:

```
var date = new Date ('2017/12/26 9:55 am');
Logger.log(date);
```