# Where is the documentation for Date on GAS?

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script

In JavaScript, the following returns a valid Date object:

`new Date('2016-10-30')`

But from a Google Apps Script, it returns an invalid date object. So it looks like the assumption that GAS's Date is just the same as JavaScript's does not hold, and I can't find it's documentation.

Comment: gas is javascript. look at the official date documentation and you will see it depends on the ecmascript version and browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Date link on
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features points to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

## See also

- [Which Edition of ECMA-262 Does Google Apps Script Support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252409/which-edition-of-ecma-262-does-google-apps-script-support)
- [How do I format this date string so that google scripts recognizes it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810441/how-do-i-format-this-date-string-so-that-google-scripts-recognizes-it)