# How to convert HTTP header date to date in Google sheets?

Tags: date, http-headers, google-sheets-formula

I get the HTTP header date into Google Sheets formatted as `Tue, 08 Dec 2020 18:15:15 GMT`. It seems to be usual Java date format, but Google Sheets doesn't recognize it as date.

I tried all in-built possibilities of Google Sheets to re-format date - no success.

How is this possible to manipulate HTTP header date from the current format into format recognized by Google Sheets as real date?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this question [Google Sheet API V4(Java) append Date in cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986171/google-sheet-api-v4java-append-date-in-cells), where a similar problem is flagged.

Also check out:
[Google Date Formats](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats)

Google Apps Script uses a particular version of JavaScript **(ECMA-262 3rd Edition)** and as you have discovered can't parse date/times in ISO 8601 format. Below is a modified function I found online:

```
var dt = new Date(getDateFromIso("2012-08-03T23:00:26-05:00"));

// http://delete.me.uk/2005/03/iso8601.html
function getDateFromIso(string) {
  try{
    var aDate = new Date();
    var regexp = "([0-9]{4})(-([0-9]{2})(-([0-9]{2})" +
        "(T([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})(:([0-9]{2})(\\.([0-9]+))?)?" +
        "(Z|(([-+])([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})))?)?)?)?";
    var d = string.match(new RegExp(regexp));

    var offset = 0;
    var date = new Date(d[1], 0, 1);

    if (d[3]) { date.setMonth(d[3] - 1); }
    if (d[5]) { date.setDate(d[5]); }
    if (d[7]) { date.setHours(d[7]); }
    if (d[8]) { date.setMinutes(d[8]); }
    if (d[10]) { date.setSeconds(d[10]); }
    if (d[12]) { date.setMilliseconds(Number("0." + d[12]) * 1000); }
    if (d[14]) {
      offset = (Number(d[16]) * 60) + Number(d[17]);
      offset *= ((d[15] == '-') ? 1 : -1);
    }

    offset -= date.getTimezoneOffset();
    time = (Number(date) + (offset * 60 * 1000));
    return aDate.setTime(Number(time));
  } catch(e){
    return;
  }
}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810441/how-do-i-format-this-date-string-so-that-google-scripts-recognizes-it)