# Methods for Date class?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there any documentation for what I can do to an object created like "new Date()"? I thought it would be a Javascript date object, but it doesn't seem to have most of the methods of that object.

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think it is not a normal JavaScript object?  What method doesn't work?  Can you elaborate or illustrate?

Answer (score 1):

indeed it is a JS object and have all the JS object [methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp). But the autocompletion is only available for the google apps scripts class and some a few time for some js native objects like array.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into a Date related issue in Google Apps Script where Javascript in my browser console would correctly interpret a date (in the format "2014-08-26T11:25:01.000-0400"), but the GAS Date object would not and result in "Invalid Date".

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683978/255008) to another question where in a comment it was mentioned that GAS uses Rhino to interpret Javascript.  I downloaded [several versions of Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Download_Rhino) until I found one old enough that gave me the same error (Rhino 1.7R5, Jan. 29, 2015).

You can download that version and peruse the source code and even run the interpreter with a REPL using the command `java -jar js.jar`.  To answer your question, **src/org/mozilla/javascript/NativeDate.java** would be the file you're looking for, and the definition of the Date object is down near the bottom where a bunch of `private static final int`s are declared (ex: Id_constructor, Id_toString, etc.)  I think those ints correspond to methods in the same Java class that define the Javascript Date object.